# Laplacian eigenvalue on a domain with singularities

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\mathbb{B}$ is the compact unit disc with boundary with center at orgin, now we consider $\Omega=\mathbb{B}\setminus \{z: \operatorname{Re}(z)=0\}$. Does following eigenvalue problem make sense?
$$\Delta u=\lambda u \text{ in }\Omega;\  u=0 \text{ on} \ \partial \Omega$$ 
Is there any difference with the eigenvalue problem on the disc?